# excel macro to create new row for number diff

Tags: vba, excel

I need to take column A which has 2 values in a single cell and create a row for each number between the two values but keeping the rest of the columns the same as it was in the original row.

[image]

Here is my current macro.

Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Dim CellValue As String
    strcellvalue = Replace(Range("A9").Value, " ", "")
    If InStr(strcellvalue, "-") Then
        Dim intCurrentBIN As Double
        Dim intLastBIN As Double
        Dim intMainRow As Integer
        Dim intNewRow As Integer
        intMainRow = 9
        intNewRow = intMainRow + 1

```
    intCurrentBIN = CDbl(Left(strcellvalue, InStr(strcellvalue, "-") - 1))
    intLastBIN = CDbl(Right(strcellvalue, Len(strcellvalue) - InStr(strcellvalue, "-")))

        Do While intCurrentBIN < (intLastBIN + 1)
            Rows(intMainRow & ":" & intMainRow).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Rows(intNewRow & ":" & intNewRow).Select
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
            Range("A" & intNewRow).Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = intCurrentBIN
            intNewRow = intNewRow + 1
            intCurrentBIN = intCurrentBIN + 1
        Loop
    Rows(intMainRow & ":" & intMainRow).Select
    Selection.Delete
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: The best way to get help here is to first try something. If you get stuck, do some research, make an attempt at fixing things yourself, and only then ask a specific question about your attempts. Questions asking for complete solutions without demonstrating research effort usually get downvoted and closed.

Comment: Seems you need to start looking into VBA and regular expressions. Regular expressions splitting up the text into numbers and then looping through "the_difference" times to print the number and copying description and code to a newly added line within the loop.

Comment: I have this so far which works on my example but not on my file itself. Will check and find if i can improve it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely clear as to what your issue is. Your code works fine. Below is a piece of code that works and does the same job without inserting lines:

Sub createRows()

```
Dim iStart As Integer, iEnd As Integer, iLastRow As Integer, iThreeFour As Integer, iLoop As Integer
Dim sID As String, sDesc As String, sCode As String

For iThreeFour = 3 To 4

    sID = Range("A" & iThreeFour)
    sDesc = Range("B" & iThreeFour)
    sCode = Range("C" & iThreeFour)

    iStart = Left(sID, InStr(sID, "-") - 1)
    iEnd = Right(sID, Len(sID) - InStr(sID, "-"))
    iLastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    For iLoop = iStart To iEnd

        Range("A" & iLastRow).Value = iLoop
        Range("B" & iLastRow).Value = sDesc
        Range("C" & iLastRow).Value = sCode

        iLastRow = iLastRow + 1

    Next iLoop

Next iThreeFour
```

End Sub